# SOAP API Automating testing with ROBOTFRAMEWORK

Tags: soap, robotframework, web-api-testing

Good day,

I am trying to use robot framework to test a soap based api. I tried using the RobotFramework-Soap library first. I tried a sample case and it works but as soon as I put in my api link it does not work. Im not sure if it is because my api link contains an api.

N.B. due to confidentiality I am unable to post the actual api link. But it is in the format shown below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SoapLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Create Soap Client    http://000.000.000.000:8000/SomeService?wsdl
    ${response}    Call SOAP Method With XML    ${CURDIR}/request.xml
    ${text}    Get Data From XML By Tag    ${response}    AddResult
    Log To Console    ${text}
    Save XML To File    ${response}    ${CURDIR}    response_test
```

When I run the above test. It fails with following error:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxx_cert', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /SomeService?xsd=xsd0 (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

I even tried using the suds library as well. and when i do a simple test as follows:

```
***Test Cases***
Example
    Create Soap Client      http://000.000.000.000:8000/SomeService?wsdl
```

I get the following error: URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

I did some searching and I found that it could be related to the port. But Im not sure how to resolve this issue.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Lee

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to edit the local host file to cater for the web service. That seemed to solve all the problems.